# predict function and linear regression model

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

I have a quick question (hopefully). Let's say that I have 2 predictors, HL (categorical) and X (continuous) and I regress Y(continuous) on these to predictors and the interaction-term X:HL.

```
HL <- as.factor(rep(c("high","low"),each=10))
set.seed(19)
X <- runif(20,1,5)
set.seed(2)
Y <- runif(20,1,5)
df <- data.frame(HL,X,Y)
fit <- lm(Y~HL*X,df) 
summary(fit)

fit <- lm(Y~HL*X,df)
summary(fit)

  Call:
  lm(formula = Y ~ HL * X, data = df)

  Residuals:
      Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
  -1.4763 -0.9949 -0.3215  1.0109  1.9323 

  Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
  (Intercept)   2.7353     0.9549   2.864   0.0112 *
  HL1          -0.5280     0.9549  -0.553   0.5879  
  X             0.1252     0.2951   0.424   0.6769  
  HL1:X         0.2372     0.2951   0.804   0.4333
```

Now, the predicted value (CI,SE etc.) for X = 4 when HL = "high"

```
 new <- data.frame("HL"="high", "X" = 4)
 predict(fit, se.fit = T, newdata = new,interval="confidence", level=0.95 )
```

The result is:

```
 $fit
       fit      lwr      upr
 1 3.657078 2.268731 5.045425
 $se.fit
 [1] 0.6549099
 $df
 [1] 16
 $residual.scale
 [1] 1.28098
```

Lets say that I am only interested in the predicted value for X = 4

```
 new <- data.frame("X" = 4)
 predict(fit, se.fit = T, newdata = new,interval="confidence", level=0.95 )
```

Because I didn't specify 'HL' this time, R returns an error. 
But is it possible with the predict function (or another function) to get the predicted value for X = 4  for the model specified above without providing a value for 'HL'?

Thank you very much in advance,
L.

Answer (score 1):

No, because your model expects 2 predictors (plus inxn); thus your model specifies that the predicted value depends on both X and HL. So the predicted value of 'X==4' isn't unique until HL is defined. You could compute a range by varying HL by way of expand.grid, but I'm not sure that solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer... no, sadly not... but its good to know that this won't work because i spend some time trying to get a result somehow. I simply thought that predict() only uses the the coefficient for X (0.1252) to calculate a predicted value when HL is not specified, but it makes sense.